# CSS: how to enforce word wrap on an odd situation?

Tags: css, word-wrap

Have a look at this fiddle where [it is tried to wrap text in the yellow div without setting its width or the outer divs width - only by using the width of the inner div](http://jsbin.com/atocaz/6/edit)

Is there something I could do to achieve this?

thanks a lot

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using pure CSS. An element has no concept of the width its siblings, just of its parent and/or children.

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't put a width defined div surrounding both the orange and yellow, but not the outer div?

Comment: really? so I could set the width of the parent by setting it to the width of its child? eg span div /div /span  where div has width 100 - how to set outter span to 100 as well?

Comment: @RobertChrist the problem is that the orange can have different sizes - there are 3 different sizes possible for orange. 900 px, 500px, and 1200 px updated my question (in 5 s)

Comment: and the main reason to not add a DIV because it will get used in a framework with ~1000 pages

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set `#h`'s width to `100px` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't make sense why you wouldn't just set `#h`'s width to 100, you can try this:

```
#a{
    background-color: grey;
    padding:5px;
    display: table;
}
#b{
    width: 100px !important;
    background-color: orange;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding:5px;
    display: table-cell;
}
#h{
    background-color: yellow;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding:5px;
    display: table-row;
}
```

I think we can help you more if you tell us why exactly you don't want to define `#h`'s width explicitly, but I hope that this helped anyway.

Comment: since I don't know what width the element inside will have, I just know that there will be an element with a defined width in there

Comment: actually I don't understand your solution - but it obviously works :-D would you mind to share why it works?

Comment: @Toskan Basically you're emulating the way `table`s behave using CSS. In `table`s, cells are kind of "linked" to each other -- you can't have a column in which cells have different widths (nor a row in which cells have different heights), and since, in our case, one of the "cells" has its `width` explicitly defined, all other cells in its column "inherit" it (not the best technical term, but I think the point is clear). Again, hope that helped!